# Switch multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, switch-statement

I hava a switch statement like this:

```
switch(intCount){
       case 0:
            run();
            break;
       case 1:
            run();
            break;
       case 2:
            stop();
            break;
       case 3:
            stop();
            break;
}
```

All I want to do is abbreviate to this:

```
switch(intCount){
     case 0 || 1:
             run();
             break;
     case 2 || 3:
             stop();
             break;
}
```

Not sure how to do it though. Thought || would do "or", but it's not. Also I don't want to do case < 1: As I want to be able to group random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
switch(intCount){
       case 0:
       case 1:
            run();
            break;
       case 2:
       case 3:
            stop();
            break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Was a bit stumped by this.